# Cannot import Banshee audio since I upgraded to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, banshee

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. Since the upgrade I can no longer import audio media in Banshee. As soon as I select any folder Banshee either hangs or crashes. I have found plenty of references to people having similar problems but the only solution I found was to disable all extensions. I have tried doing this but to no avail.

Is there anything else I can do to get Import working again?

Answer (score 3):

Having a very similar problem. I can import music from CD, but attempting to import from a folder (in the file tree where all the music already in Banshee lives) has been failing since the upgrade.

I can select one of the files in a folder that I can't import, select Banshee as the app to open it with, and it plays just fine in the File System Queue.

Have sent multiple crash reports.

As mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/1687220,
as a workaround, if the folder in question is in the "Music Folder" tree, rescanning the music library will add it to the library.
(Just confirmed that this works.).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare machine, install a lightweight/minimal Ubuntu 16.04 derivative, e.g. wattOS 10, just to run Banshee, which is what I do.

Alternatively, install 16.04, or a derivative, in a separate partition, or in a virtual machine.